# Getting a list of cells that contain substring using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering how I can generate a list of cells in Excel file that contain a given substring using VBA. This should be able to find the cells regardless of the upper/lower case.

An example is:

[image]

[image]

Given the user-defined inputs (apple and berry), it sholud return the second picture.

How do I do this in VBA?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even if it didn't work, it's worth [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52615816/edit) and posting it as it will save us going over already covered ground.

Comment: Are you having trouble filtering the list, or converting the results into the image?

Comment: @Comintern I am having trouble writing the code that filters the list.. not converting the result into the image.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say generate a list... So I assume you won't override your old data.

This code checks for the two values in worksheet "Sheet1". Then compares the two values you define against the cell value in your data (your data is assumed to be in Column A, from row 1 and downwards). If either of defined values exist in the cell (apple or berry, regardless of small/big letters), it's considered a match. If match is found it will copy the value to the first empty row in Column B.

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub SearchAndExtract()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim lrowNewList As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lookupValue As String
Dim lookupValue2 As String
Dim currentValue As String
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Set MySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lookupValue = "*apple*" 'First name you want to search for. Use * for wildcard
lookupValue2 = "*berry*" 'Second name you want to search for. Use * for wildcard

lrow = MySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in your data column
lrowNewList = MySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in the column you want to paste to

For i = 1 To lrow 'From Row 1 to last row in the column where you want to check your data
    currentValue = MySheet.Cells(i, "A").Value 'Define the string value you have in your current cell
    If LCase$(currentValue) Like LCase$(lookupValue) Or _
       LCase$(currentValue) Like LCase$(lookupValue2) Then 'LCase for case sensitivity, it check the current cell against the two lookup values. If either of those are find, then
            MySheet.Cells(lrowNewList, "B") = MySheet.Cells(i, "A") 'Copy from current cell in column a to last blank cell in column B
            lrowNewList = lrowNewList + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to replace your new table with your old at the same column, I would just delete Column A with the old data. Add this to the vba code after `Next i`:
`Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete`